# Why $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\tan^{-1}t - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \frac{\pi}{4} $?

Tags: calculus

This is an example with solution from Calculus by Stewart.

$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\tan^{-1}t - \frac{\pi}{4} \right) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\pi}{4} $

this is just a calculation needed for other stuff they are explaining, but I totally missed how they calcualted this limit

Comment: When $x\to {\pi\over 2,}^-$ then $\tan x\to \infty.$ The function $\tan x$ is increasing on $ [0,{\pi\over 2}).$

Comment: $\tan^{-1} t \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ as $t\to+\infty$ because $\tan x\to +\infty$ as $x\to \frac{\pi}{2}-0$. See the graph of the inverse tangent [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangent.html).

Comment: Provided the limits exist, in general we have $\lim(X+Y)=\lim X+\lim Y$.  Additionally, given a constant $k$, we have $\lim k=k$.

Comment: got it. Guess I need to pay more attention to graphs of trascendential functions

Comment: Knowing the graph helps you remember, but if ever there is a time to try and manipulate the limit yourself via substitution, it would be now.

Comment: You just lack knowledge about what is arctan because it's by définition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tan^{-1}(t)$ is increasing and bounded between $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

I'll focus on $t>0$:

For $t>0$, let $f(t)=tan(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)}$
notice at $t=\pi/2$ we get singularity:
$\lim_{t \to  \frac{\pi}{2}^- }   \tan ( t )   =   \infty$

For every $0<t<\frac{\pi}{2}$ there's $u>0$ s.t $f(t)=u$ and $ f^{-1}(u)=t$

We know that if $f$ is increasing, so does $ f^{-1}$ but the highst value $t$ can get is $\frac{\pi}{2}$, so the limit of increasing function with an upper bound is the upper bound itself, $\frac{\pi}{2}$